# Creating a circular hole in a UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, cgcontext

I am using this code to create a circular hole in UIImageVIew

```
 let r = imageView.bounds
    let r2 = CGRect(x: (mainScroll.contentOffset.x + 30), y:(mainScroll.contentOffset.y + UIScreen.main.bounds.height - radius + 30), width: radius - 60, height: radius - 60)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(r.size,false, 0)
    let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    c?.addRect(r2)
    c?.addRect(r)
    c?.clip()


    c?.setFillColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 0.5)
    c?.fill(r2)
    let imagefinal1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return imagefinal1!
```

My Question is possible to get the clipped image, because This code creates a hole.

Comment: do you want a rounded image ?

Comment: I want to save the cropped part of the image. My current image is with full image with circular hole. I want to save the circular hole due to crop